# No test run when running maven test command

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

There is a maven project hosted by someone else, which has `src/main` directory and `src/test` directory. The `src/test` dir contains a java file ending with `Test`, I'll just call it `ATest.java`, and the class `ATest` only contains a static void **main** function. It is like

```
//omitted

public class ATest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BTester.main(null);
        CTester.main(null);
    }
}
```

where `BTester` and `CTester` are both files under directory 
 `src/main/java/<package_path>/tester`

When I type `mvn clean test`, it shows

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I tried the following methods:

1. `import org.junit.Test` and add `@Test` descriptor ahead of the main function, but it gives error because main is static and it accepts parameters. Then I tried to move `BTester.main` and `CTester.main` to another function `testmain` and add `@Test` before `testmain`, but it causes errors when compiling, saying that I have uncaught exception, even if I add `throws Exception`?
2. use the `maven-surefire-plugin`, here is how I did it in the `pom.xml` file

   `<plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.20</version>
       <configuration>
           <includes>
               <include>ATest.java</include>
           </includes>
       </configuration> 
   </plugin>`

But it still doesn't work.

What did I miss? I'm not very familiar with Java, not with maven, so I really need some help now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to place your test class under /src/test/java.
2. You need your test method. Do not using main for test method using JUNIT
   See this reference: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Actually I have tried method 2 yesterday, but it just didn't work for some unknown resaons, and it suddenly works now... maybe I made some stupid mistakes. But anyway the problem is solved.

Comment: Whilst the answer and the OP code are correct, people should also not forget to end the name of their class "Test", So if I'm testing MyCode then MyCodeTest. Surefire by default looks for items ending in "Test".